# How can I create a platform independent SDK?

Tags: linux, sdk, development-environment

I have to develop a platform independent SDK which will allow users to create apps and run certain scripts. These scripts are developed in C++, OPenCV, python.

I am thinking to develop a VM which will have the necessary setup to run C++, python scripts. And then release a .ova file. 
Users can run the ova file. Users need to login into the VM.

But I do not know how to create such a tool. Can anyone please help me understand the procedure and method for developing such a SDK.

Comment: If you are creating virtual machine, then you have one platform. What is the problem in this case?

Comment: @Ivan Thank you for your time. I have found some tools where they ask the users to run a .ova file with a given login credential. Once logged in the VM somehow connect to the IP of the same machine running the .ova file. And user can access the tool in his browser using the IP displayed in the VM. This way the VM configurations and scripts are hidden from user. I want to develop the SDK in such manner. But I do not know how to develop such a VM and such a tool. Could you please suggest me something.

Comment: And this way the SDK can run on any operating system (platform independent). The users need to run the .ova file on which ever platform they use (windows, linux). The SDK can be accessed through browser.

Comment: @Ivan any suggestions ??

Comment: I saw another SDK : [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_(software)), it is also built around virtual machine idea

Comment: If you understand how such tools are built, it would be nice for me to learn.